# Databricks jdbc driver for Cubejs ( cube.dev)

Tags: jdbc, cube, databricks-sql

We are trying to connect cube olap engine to databricks sql using jdbc driver (https://github.com/cube-js/cube.js/tree/master/packages/cubejs-databricks-jdbc-driver). We want to use Cube as olap layer for fast query and pre-aggregations.

However, it seems the jdbc connectoris not working. Has anyone seen this issue or tried connecting cube to databricks sql

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible right now but Databricks driver is planned to be delivered in Q4 this year.

Comment: Please, as per the rules, use the comments if you don't have to post code.